# Fstream outputs after exit

Tags: c++, output, fstream

I have a problem. I use fstream to print to a file, but it's not printing in real-time, it outputs everything after I close the program (like it stores all data while the program is running and prints everything at once after exit). And if I hide the console `FreeConsole();` it won't output anything even after exit. I didn't have that problem before (like a half year ago).

Anyways here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

std::fstream file("xx.txt", std::ios::out);

int main()
{
    FreeConsole();
    while(true)
    {
        file << "X";
        Sleep(500);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken. It flushes everything when you close the file. Not when  you exit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want data to appear instantly, you need to `flush` the file:

```
file << "X"; 
file.flush();
```

`ofstream` internally maintains a buffer of written data which is written out to the actual file when you call `flush` or `close`. This buffer exists to reduce the amount of disk I/O incurred when writing repeatedly to a file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I didn't use `flush();` before and had no problems though.

Comment: Your old code might have been very different. I can't comment on code I haven't seen.

Comment: It was basically the same :) Nevermind, good that it works now.